# How to set path for non-interactive shell in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, .bash-profile

I'm new to unix and i'm trying to set the path for non-interactive shell in Solaris for the root user and all users. Checking to find the root profile didn't find any .profile or .bashrc or any of this kind in the /. The only existing profile is the /etc/profile

```
#ident  "@(#)profile    1.19    01/03/13 SMI"   /* SVr4.0 1.3   */

# The profile that all logins get before using their own .profile.

trap ""  2 3
export LOGNAME PATH

if [ "$TERM" = "" ]
then
    if /bin/i386
    then
            TERM=sun-color
    else
            TERM=sun
    fi
    export TERM
fi

#       Login and -su shells get /etc/profile services.
#       -rsh is given its environment in its .profile.

case "$0" in
-sh | -ksh | -jsh | -bash)

    if [ ! -f .hushlogin ]
    then
            /usr/sbin/quota
            #       Allow the user to break the Message-Of-The-Day only.
            trap "trap '' 2"  2
            /bin/cat -s /etc/motd
            trap "" 2

            /bin/mail -E
            case $? in
            0) 
                    echo "You have new mail."
                    ;;
            2) 
                    echo "You have mail."
                    ;;
            esac
    fi
esac

umask 022
trap  2 3
```

Should i add the path

> PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin

in that or should i create a new profile?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default path is set in the `/etc/default/login` file on Solaris.

For regular users, the `PATH` variable is used, for root, that's `SUPATH`.

Comment: i checked what you suggested and `PATH` and `SUPATH` are both commented out. I assume it takes it some somewhere else.

Comment: There is no "somewhere else" outside hard coded values. Just uncomment them in /etc/default/login and add your customizations. Their commented valued is the default they got otherwise.